# Get Pi from Ehrenfest model

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

It is well-known [Buffon's needle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem) and obtained $\pi $ with it — both in real experiments and programming simulations.
By analogy, I became interested in a [Ehrenfest model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_model).
It is proved that if we start at equilibrium (equal number of particles in the containers), the expected time to return to equilibrium is asymptotically equal to $\sqrt{\pi N/2}$ where $N$ is number of particles.
I tried to do numerical experiments, noting the gaps between returns to  equilibrium, and get $\pi $ from them, but the results were very unstable.
So is it possible somehow to implement a numerical Ehrenfest model to get something similar to [these results?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem#/media/File:Buffon_needle_experiment_compressed.gif)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how exactly did you do your numerical experiments? The Buffon problem kinda has only one way to simulate it (apart from varying insignificant parameters such as the size of the arena you're throwing matches into), but it seems like you could choose several approaches for the Ehrenfest problem.